# Unable to download files from s3 using vpc endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-iot-greengrass

So I have created a VPC Interface endpoint for S3.
I have tried running the below command:

```
aws s3api getobject --bucket <bucketname> --key <file_key> --endpoint-url https://<bucketname>.bucket.s3. 
<region>.amazonaws.com
```

and it works fine.

Then I tried to update my /etc/hosts file with the 2 subnet IPs of my VPC like below:

```
<subnet-ip-1> s3.<region>.amazonaws.com
<subnet-ip-2> s3.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

And then I do a aws s3 ls. Works fine- I can see all my buckets

Then I run the below command (1st command excluding endpoint-url):

```
aws s3api getobject --bucket <bucketname> --key <file_key> <local_file_name>
```

Timeout error.
I try -

```
aws s3 cp s3://<bucketname>/<filekey> <local_file_name>
```

Timeout again..

Then I updated my /etc/hosts file like below..

```
<subnet-ip-1> <bucketname>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com
<subnet-ip-2> <bucketname>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

And I ran the command..

```
aws s3 cp s3://<bucketname>/<filekey> <local_file_name>
```

It works!!
But I cant add bucket names like this because I have almost 100 such buckets. And I cannot use endpoint url in my s3 commands because Im setting this up for greengrass. And greengrass wont allow me to configure a s3 endpoint. So it has to be like greengrass will call its bucket commands at s3..amazonaws.com but they should be redirected to my VPC endpoint by default.

How do I set that up?
Note: I do not and cannot hv internet access.

Comment: Why do you update `/etc/hosts`? You didn;t enable any vpc name resolutions or interface name resolution?

Comment: @Marcin How do u do that?